# Spring security - complex logic deciding whether to require login, or allow anonymous access

Tags: spring-security

Using spring securiity, I'm faced with a requirement for a complex business decision about whether to allow anonymous access or insist on user login. Logic is too complex for "intercept-url" expressions ( intercept-url pattern='/mypattern/**'...)

```
E.g. assume a RESTFul books service:
https://myserver/rest/book?title=war_and_peace
https://myserver/rest/book?title=the_firm

Say "war and peace" allows anonymous access because its old and its copyrights have expired.
While "the firm" is copyrighted & requires login (so as to charge the user).
This copyright info is available in a database.
```

Could anyone please offer any hints as to how to achieve this in spring secuirity? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are of course multiple ways that code can look like, but to get the idea:

```java
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
if (auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken && "the_firm".equals(title)) {
    throw new AccessDeniedException("Requires login!");
}
```

**Update:** A more declarative way is to use annotations:

```java
@PostAuthorize("hasPermission(returnObject, 'READ')")
public Book findBook(String title) {
    // ...
}
```

This requires that you create a [permission evaluator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/PermissionEvaluator.html) bean and add config:

```xml
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
  <expression-handler ref="expressionHandler" />
</global-method-security>
```

```java
@Bean
public DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler() {
    DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler handler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    handler.setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluator);
    return handler;
}
```

Comment: thanks, indeed I see this exception has a unique usage in the framework so as to popup a challenge for the credentials. Much appreciated. Still I wonder whether there is a more declarative way? 
Something in the lines of "intercept-url pattern=TITLE_COPYRIGHTED access=ROLE_USER"?